# Is this a correct question?

Tags: geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

> **Q.** Find the *shortest distance* between two *non-intersecting lines* passing through the points whose position vectors are **a** and **b** are parallel to vectors **c** and **d** respectively.

My confusion is : two non-intersecting lines *must be always parallel*.They must have a **constant distance** between them.What is the point of asking *shortest distance* between two lines if they are parallel?

Wikipedia says:

> In geometry, parallel lines are lines in a plane **which do not meet**; that is, two lines in a plane **that do not intersect or touch each other** at any point are said to be parallel. By extension, a line and a plane, or two planes, in three-dimensional Euclidean space that **do not share a point** are said to be parallel. However, two lines in three-dimensional space which **do not meet** ***must be in a common plane*** to be considered parallel.

Does the last sentence means that if two lines are not coplanar and not intersecting,then they are not  parallel?Then,do they have different distance at different points?

Comment: Maybe the question is asking for the distance between two line *segments*?

Comment: No.They are lines.

Comment: The question at the beginning most likely doesn't require lines to be in a plane

Comment: If you are in a 3D space, you have a minimum distance between two lines that do not intersect. They are on parallel planes.

Comment: And the last sentence to which your refer in your ending questions states that if two lines are not parallel and do not meet, then they are not coplanar.

Comment: Lines in three dimensional space which are not parallel and not coplanar are **skew** lines, and there is indeed a shortest distance between them which you can calculate using scalar and cross product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. It's called Skew lines, which means that two lines, in three-dimensional space, does not intersect and aren't parallel.